# Ограничение на выполнение программы для WebAssembly

Tags: golang, webassembly

Кто может подсказать, почему следующий код на Go скомпилированный в wasm в JS не работает с циклом свыше миллиона?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var testStr strings.Builder
    var count int
    count = 1000000
    testStr.WriteString("SSSS")
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        testStr.WriteString("AA")
    }
    fmt.Println(testStr.Len())
    fmt.Println("TEST")
}
```

```
wasm_exec.js:117 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot perform DataView.prototype.setUint32 on a neutered ArrayBuffer
    at DataView.setUint32 (<anonymous>)
    at setInt64 (wasm_exec.js:117)
    at runtime.nanotime (wasm_exec.js:253)
    at runtime.nanotime (wasm-function[893]:9)
    at runtime.checkTimeouts (wasm-function[158]:135)
    at runtime.gopark (wasm-function[479]:872)
    at runtime.notetsleepg (wasm-function[157]:930)
    at runtime.gcBgMarkStartWorkers (wasm-function[275]:403)
    at runtime.gcStart (wasm-function[272]:1238)
    at runtime.mallocgc (wasm-function[167]:2671)
```

Причем при `count = 100000` всё работает:

```
Console was cleared
wasm_exec.js:41 200004
wasm_exec.js:41 TEST
```

- Go: `version 1-13rc2`
- Chrome `Version 76.0.3809.132 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)`
- Windows 10 Pro Version 1903(Build 18362.295)

Comment: Не воспроизводится. Добавьте в вопрос версии го, ОС, и браузера или Ноды.

Comment: не знаю как добавить:)
Go - version 1-13rc2
Browser Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)
OS - Windows 10 Pro

Comment: На будущее: кнопка «Править» внизу вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо:) кнопка громко сказано:)) не увидел